# First countability requirement of the Sequence Lemma

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Consider the Sequence Lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $A\subseteq X$ any subset and $x\in X$. If there is a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $x$, then $x\in\bar A$; the converse holds if $X$ is first-countable.

In the proof of the converse provided [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequence_Lemma) they define a sequence of the elements of the neighborhood basis $\mathcal{U}$ of $x$ as $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then they define the sequence of non-empty sets $\{S_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ as $S_i = A \cap (\cap_{k=1}^i U_k)$. Finally they create the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $x_i \in S_i$, and as $x_i \rightarrow x$ then the proof is complete.

As far as I understand the first-countability condition is used to assert the existence of a bijective function $\sigma: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{U}$ which we can use to create the sequence $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ by making $U_i = \sigma(i)$. I do not understand why the first-countability condition is needed, as I will explain now. Consider the case where $\mathcal{U}$ is uncountable, and let $\mathbb{U}$ be an uncountable well-ordered set. Then we take a bijective function $\omega: \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{U}$ and use it to define the sequence $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{U}}$ as $U_i = \omega(i)$. The rest of the proof follows in the same way.

My question is: What is the flaw in my reasoning, and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably in this context, a "sequence" is by definition indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You have 2 problems: (1) even if your proof works, the results sequence of $x_i$ will be of size $\mathbb U$, and not $\mathbb N$ (which we usually mean by when we talk about sequences in topology) and (2) why is $A∩(∩_{k=1}^ω U_k≠∅$? (Where $ω$ is the smallest element of $\mathbb U$ such that $\{i<ω\mid i∈\mathbb{U}\}$ is infinite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in the context of topology, a "sequence" is defined to be indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, not by an arbitrary well-ordered set.  So if your $\mathbb{U}$ is different from $\mathbb{N}$, what you are constructing is simply not a sequence at all.

Even if your definition allows sequences indexed by any well-ordered set, though, the argument still does not work.  The issue is that you know that $S_i = A \cap (\bigcap_{k=1}^i U_k)$ is nonempty because $\bigcap_{k=1}^i U_k$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $x\in\overline{A}$.  However, if $i$ is an element of your uncountable well-ordered set $\mathbb{U}$, there may be infinitely many $k\leq i$, so you would be taking an infinite intersection of neighborhoods of $x$ which may no longer be a neighborhood of $x$.  Consequently, $S_i$ could be empty and there could be no way to pick $x_i$.

Comment: From the definition of neighborhood basis the intersection $\cap_{k=1}^i U_k$ must be a superset of some neighborhood $U_j$, for any finite $i$. However, this no longer holds if $i$ is infinite, correct?

Comment: Well, that's true but not really relevant.  The relevant point is just that the intersection does not have to be a neighborhood since open sets only have to be closed under finite intersections.

Comment: Yes, but if such intersection were to contain a neighborhood then $S_i$ would not be empty. That's not the case anyway. Thank you very much.